# Get All products by product category ID in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Get All products by category id not working in functions.php on shortcode.

```
    add_shortcode( 'sigma_gift', 'wpdocs_sigma_func' );

function wpdocs_sigma_func() { 
    global $product; 

    $content = '<fieldset><div class="custom-products row">';
    $args =
        array(
           'post_type'   => 'product',
            'numberposts' => -1,
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'tax_query'   => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                    'field'    => 'term_id',
                    'terms'    => '22',
                    'operator' => 'IN',
                ),
            ),
        );

    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );

    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); 
        echo "test";
        

        $content .= '<div class="product-layout product-grid module-style1 col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 category">
                <div class="product-thumb">
                    <div class="item item2">
                        <div class="item-inner">
                            <div class="col-image">
                                <div class="image images-container">
                                    <img src="'.woocommerce_placeholder_img_src().'" alt="'.esc_attr($loop->post->post_title ? $loop->post->post_title : $loop->post->ID).'" title="'.esc_attr($loop->post->post_title ? $loop->post->post_title : $loop->post->ID).'" class="img-responsive">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-des">
                                <div class="caption">
                                    <h4 class="product-name">'.esc_attr($loop->post->post_title ? $loop->post->post_title : $loop->post->ID).'</h4>
                                    <div class="center_button">   <input type="radio" name="productRadio" value="'.$loop->post->ID.'" required="required"> </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>';
                    
    endwhile;
    wp_reset_query(); 

    $content .= '</div></fieldset>';
    return  $content;
}
```

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: The query is correct and works, so there is something else that is making trouble…  See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @LoicTheAztec, it's return empty array

Comment: @LoicTheAztec, Code updated in question block

Comment: So where are you using this shortcode exactly? I don't see any explanations related… Try to be more explicit, with words (details), your screenshots are not enough.